# (NS_ERROR_MALFORMED_URI) [nsIIOService.newURI] When executing a user keyword taking 'URL' as arguments

Tags: selenium-webdriver, robotframework

When I execute the user keyword, I get the following error:

```
Message: u'Component returned failure code: 0x804b000a (NS_ERROR_MALFORMED_URI) [nsIIOService.newURI]'
```

My test:

```
*** Settings ***
Library           lib_TestSetUp.py
Library           CP_Web_SignInPage.py

*** Test Cases ***
TC1
  ${wd_handle}=    Initiate Setup    'Firefox'
  Login User    ${wd_handle}    'http://www.amazon.com/cloudplayer'    'karthicm+ustest1@amazon.com'    'test123'
```

When I run, webdriver handle is set to ${wd_handle} and I use the same handler to run my remaining tests on the ride.

```
def login_user(wd_handle, Login_URL, UserName, Password):
    {
     //Does login operation
    }
```

Console:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 551, in __bootstrap_inner
self.run()
 File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 504, in run
self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
 File "C:\Python27\Lib\SocketServer.py", line 225, in serve_forever
r, w, e = select.select([self], [], [], poll_interval)
```

AttributeError: `'module' object has no attribute 'select'`

Log:

```
Starting test: DigitalMP3 Project.TestSuite.TC1
20130603 16:26:44.629 :  INFO : ${wd_handle} = <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver.WebDriver object at 0x03302790>
20130603 16:26:49.720 :  INFO : 
Message: u'Component returned failure code: 0x804b000a (NS_ERROR_MALFORMED_URI) [nsIIOService.newURI]'
```

INFO:

`RIDE 1.1 running on Python 2.7.3`.

robotframework-2.7.7

selenium 2.33

Comment: Do you by any chance have a file named `select.py` that might get laded instead of the built-in select module?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the single quotes being used for the arguments 'http://www.amazon.com/cloudplayer'

Just  using - http://www.amazon.com/cloudplayer worked fine. RobotFramework by defaults takes the arguments as raw strings